# Power BI - Apply filters through values from another table and get the minimum date on another table

Tags: powerbi

I have two Tables

```
Table 1
ColA ColB 
A     B  
B     C   
A     B 

Table 2 
ColA ColB Date
A    B    1/1/2011
A    B    1/3/2017
```

I have the Col A and ColB as two different filters from Table 1. I am trying to take the filter selected values from there and Identify the Minimum date for that combination in Table2.

Because of my data model, I am not able to use the ColA ColB from Table2 as filters on my front end.

Expected output when A and B are selected will be 1/1/2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the minimum date over a filtered table.

A calculated column on `Table 1` would look like this:

```
 = MINX(
       FILTER('Table 2',
           'Table 2'[ColA] = EARLIER('Table 1'[ColA]) &&
           'Table 2'[ColB] = EARLIER('Table 1'[ColB])),
       'Table 2'[Date])
```

If you want it as a measure, then replace `EARLIER` with `MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

From `Table2`, create a new `Table3` (by reference) with the three columns, combine `ColA` & `ColB` to new column `CombinedAB`, then sort (date descending) & filter the unique `CombinedAB`.  Given your example, the new table would then have
`ColA   ColB    Date  CombinedAB
    A      B  1/1/11     AB`

Next, in `Table1`, combine `ColA` & `ColB` to `NewAB`, then join the `Table1` & `Table3` based on  `NewAB` & `CombinedAB` and select the `Date` from `Table3` fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below measure should do

```
Measure = CALCULATE(MIN(Table2[Date]),
                    FILTER(Table2,  
                               Table2[A]=SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[A],BLANK())
                            && Table2[B]=SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[B],BLANK())
                           )
                      )
```